# How to get data from one Page in another page in php?

Tags: php

I don't know how to review the answers in judge.php .I  can just get the  answer of the last question.I know the problem is that all the radio's name is same.But I just don't know how to process!

```
<form name="frm" action="judge.php" method="post" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
    <table width="450" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">  
  <?php
    do{
  ?>     
    <tr><!-- title of  question -->
        <td height="30" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F000"><strong>
        <?php echo "$info[1]";?></strong></td>
        </tr>    <!-- First answer-->
    <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name="vote" value="0">
        <?php echo "$info[2]";?>
        </td>
        </tr>  <!--second answer-->
    <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name="vote" value="1">
        <?php echo "$info[3]";?>
        </td>
        </tr>  <!--Third answer-->
    <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name="vote" value="2">
        <?php echo "$info[4]";?>
        </td>
        </tr>  <!-- Fourth answer-->
    <tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name="vote" value="3">
        <?php echo "$info[5]";?>
        </td>
        </tr>

  <?php
   }while($info = mysql_fetch_row($result));
  ?>
   <tr>
   <td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="hidden" name="go"  value="1">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit your answer" name="submit1" onClick="javascript:return check();" >&nbsp;</td>
   </tr>
     </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a counter in the loop, say $i. And let the name of the radios be "vote".$i. So in the first iteration, the name of the radios will be vote1, in the next iteration, the name of the radios will be vote2, and so on.

```
<form name="frm" action="judge.php" method="post" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
<table width="450" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<?php
$i=0;
do{
  ?>     
<tr><!-- title of  question -->
    <td height="30" align="center" bgcolor="#F0F000"><strong>
    <?php echo "$info[1]";?></strong></td>
    </tr>    <!-- First answer-->
<tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name=<?php echo "\"vote".$i."\""; ?> value="0">
    <?php echo "$info[2]";?>
    </td>
    </tr>  <!--second answer-->
<tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name=<?php echo "\"vote".$i."\""; ?> value="1">
    <?php echo "$info[3]";?>
    </td>
    </tr>  <!--Third answer-->
<tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name=<?php echo "\"vote".$i."\""; ?> value="2">
    <?php echo "$info[4]";?>
    </td>
    </tr>  <!-- Fourth answer-->
<tr><td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="radio" name=<?php echo "\"vote".$i."\""; ?> value="3">
    <?php echo "$info[5]";?>
    </td>
    </tr>

  <?php
$i++;
}while($info = mysql_fetch_row($result));
?>
<tr>
<td height="30" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input type="hidden" name="go"  value="1">
  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" value="Submit your answer" name="submit1" onClick="javascript:return check();" >&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
 </table>
</form>
```

And then in judge.php, you can access the scores as:

```
$answers=array();
for($i=0;true;$i++) {
  if(array_key_exists("vote".$i,$_POST))
     $answers[$i]=$_POST["vote".$i];
  else
     break;
}
```

So now the $answers array contains all the answers.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works.It's time to study PHP hard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change values of 'name' attributes to something like 'vote1', 'vote2' etc.